# Does trusted_host_patterns support sub-directories?

Tags: 8

My site is installed in a sub-directory:

```
http://example.com/cms
```

When I define `trusted_host_patterns`, the following is OK:

```
$settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = array(
  '^example\.com$',
);
```

However, I cannot enforce the *host pattern* with a sub-directory, i.e.:

```
$settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = array(
  '^example\.com/cms$',
);
```

Does `trusted_host_patterns` support sub-directories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those patterns are used to check the host passed in the headers, so they cannot contain a subdirectory, since that is not passed as host. See the code in [Request::getHost()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor!symfony!http-foundation!Request.php/function/Request%3A%3AgetHost/8).

```
public function getHost() 
 {
  if ($this->isFromTrustedProxy() && self::$trustedHeaders[self::HEADER_CLIENT_HOST] && $host = $this->headers->get(self::$trustedHeaders[self::HEADER_CLIENT_HOST])) {
    $elements = explode(',', $host);

    $host = $elements[count($elements) - 1];
  }
  elseif (!$host = $this->headers->get('HOST')) {
    if (!$host = $this->server->get('SERVER_NAME')) {
      $host = $this->server->get('SERVER_ADDR', '');
    }
  }

  // trim and remove port number from host
  // host is lowercase as per RFC 952/2181
  $host = strtolower(preg_replace('/:\d+$/', '', trim($host)));

  // as the host can come from the user (HTTP_HOST and depending on the configuration, SERVER_NAME too can come from the user)
  // check that it does not contain forbidden characters (see RFC 952 and RFC 2181)
  // use preg_replace() instead of preg_match() to prevent DoS attacks with long host names
  if ($host && '' !== preg_replace('/(?:^\[)?[a-zA-Z0-9-:\]_]+\.?/', '', $host)) {
    throw new \UnexpectedValueException(sprintf('Invalid Host "%s"', $host));
  }

  if (count(self::$trustedHostPatterns) > 0) {
    // to avoid host header injection attacks, you should provide a list of trusted host patterns

    if (in_array($host, self::$trustedHosts)) {
      return $host;
    }

    foreach (self::$trustedHostPatterns as $pattern) {
      if (preg_match($pattern, $host)) {
        self::$trustedHosts[] = $host;

        return $host;
      }
    }

    throw new \UnexpectedValueException(sprintf('Untrusted Host "%s"', $host));
  }

  return $host;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you.

```
$settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = array(
 '^yourdomain\.com$',
 '^www\.yourdomain\.com$',
);
if (file_exists(__DIR__ . '/settings.local.php')) {
}
```

Wish you best of luck, this is working fine for me.